# store data from multple queries firebase(onSnapshot) , react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Iam trying to get and store date from firestore using onSnapshot(querySnapshot)
the issue is retun of the query are

the result of code bellow are 5 arrays with data, I need to store this data somehow,
I have tried useState, but it only stores last array and run infinit times.

any ideas ?

```
const go = comp?.map((CompId) => {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, "listings", CompId, "jobOffers"),
      where("activePost", "==", true)
    );
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      // setJobs(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id })));
      const test = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const newData = {
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        };
        const alreadyThere = test.findIndex((praca) => praca.id === newData.id);
        if (alreadyThere !== -1) {
          test[alreadyThere] = newData;
        } else {
          test.push(newData);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Could you also include how you return the data on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I achieved desired output

```
 const [comp, setComp] = useState();
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const x = query(collection(db, "listings"));
    const allComps = onSnapshot(x, (querySnapshot) => {
      const allCompanies = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        allCompanies.push(doc.id);
      });
      if (allCompanies.length === comp?.length) {
        console.log("ALL companies READY");
      } else {
        setComp(allCompanies);
      }
    });
    return () => allComps();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (comp?.length) {
      const unsubscribeList = comp?.map((CompId) => {
        const q = query(
          collection(db, "listings", CompId, "jobOffers"),
          where("activePost", "==", true)
        );
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
          const jobsData = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const newData = {
              id: doc.id,
              data: doc.data(),
            };
            const alreadyThere = jobsData.findIndex(
              (praca) => praca.id === newData.id
            );
            if (alreadyThere !== -1) {
              jobsData[alreadyThere] = newData;
            } else {
              jobsData.push(newData);
            }
          });
          setJobs((prevJobs) => {
            const newJobs = prevJobs.filter((job) => job.CompId !== CompId);
            return [...newJobs, { CompId, jobs: jobsData }];
          });
        });
        return unsubscribe;
      });
      return () => unsubscribeList.forEach((unsubscribe) => unsubscribe());
    }
  }, [comp]);
```